# how can i fill this mesh correctly? I need to leave spaces where required

Tags: modeling, mesh, text-object

when i press the fill tool i get incorrect results. I tried the Boolean modifier after duplicating the vertices to attempt to cut the holes in the letter 'N' etc but this didnt work. Must be something im doing wrong.. will attach some pictures to explain

EDIT: I JUST NEED TO WORK OUT HOW TO ADD THESE OUTLINES VIA THE FREESTYLE EDGE, I HAVE MARKED THEM AS SHOWN AND TRIED BUT AM NOT ABLE TO GET THEM OUTLINED

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create some edges like that and you should be able to fill the faces and cut off the hole:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the quick response mate, it worked! the only question i have is later down the line I wanted to do this effect : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nr0FAhyeOOk&list=WL&index=32&t=121s

So i can have the outline effect around the graff letters. Will these edges not end up getting the same effect?

Comment: oh ok, this is another question, you should find some answer about how to make outline in Blender, I've never done it

Comment: @JackJonnyKillick It shouldn't pose a problem, models in the video all have inner edges ;)

Comment: If that video is using grease pencil and the Line Art Modifier, no.  Line Art only does outside edges of objects.

Comment: thank you all so much, honestly! I will update with progress to see if i can get it to work

Comment: seems to go all weird with the smooth shading option? will add a pic

Comment: try to activate the Auto Smooth option in Object Data > Normals

Comment: moonboots that worked thanks again! I am nearly there, i have the outline but it is missing some details, will add another picture